# How to calculate daily evapotranspiration by hargreaves-samani equation and using python?

Tags: python, pandas, weatherdata

I have a ten-year weather data including maximum temperature (`Tmax`), minimum temperature (`Tmin`), rainfall and solar radiation (`Ra`) for each day.

At first, I would like to calculate evapotranspiration (ETo) for each day using the following equation:

```
ETo=0.0023*(((Tmax+Tmin)/2)+17.8)*sqrt(Tmax-Tmin)*Ra
```

Then, calculation of the monthly and yearly average of all parameters `(Tmax,Tmin, Rainfall, Ra and ETo)` and print them in Excel format.

I have written some parts. could you possibly help me with completing it? I think it may need a *loop*.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math as mh
# load the weather data file
data_file = pd.read_excel(r'weather data.xlsx', sheet_name='city_1')
# defining time
year = data_file['Year']
month = data_file['month']
day = data_file['day']
# defining weather parameters
Tmax = data_file.loc[:,'Tmax']
Tmin = data_file.loc[:,'Tmin']
Rainfall = data_file.loc[:,'Rainfall']
Ra = data_file.loc[:,'Ra']
# adjusting time to start at zero
year = year-year[0]
month=month-month[0]
day=day-day[0]
#calculation process for estimation of evapotranspiration
ET0=(0.0023*(((Tmax+Tmin)/2)+17.8)*(mh.sqrt(Tmax-Tmin))*Ra
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't see ```Ra```defined in the code. Is it the same as Sunhours (or derived from it).

Comment: Thank you. It's the same. I have edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've got one data row (record) per day.

Since you already have Tmax, Tmin, Rainfall, and Sunhours in the row, you could add a net ET0 row with the calculation like this:

```py
    data_file['ET0'] = data_file.apply(lambda x: 0.0023*(((x.Tmax+x.Tmin)/2)+17.8)*(mh.sqrt(x.Tmax-x.Tmin))*x.Ra, axis=0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I think we need a loop here.